# What is the antonym of "outgrow"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

It's easy to say that you outgrew your clothes, but what's the word to indicate the opposite?

> I lost so much weight that I _ _ _ _ _ my belt!

Comment: the antonym to grow is shrink, but I do not see an antonym to the idiom outgrow

Comment: Why not these: **I lost so much weight that my belt cannot hold my pants**, **I lost so much weight that my belt has gotten too loose to support my pants.**

Comment: "had to shorten"

Comment: *had to poke new holes in*

Comment: You mean you can't say _He's lost so much weight lately that he ingrew his trousers_?

Comment: I never thought about it until now but ***"outgrow"*** is a strange word in that (to me), it implies that my growing outpaced the growing of the article of clothing.  What sense does that make?  No wonder there is no exact antonym! ;-)

Comment: My belt outgrew me?

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but [Freedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grow+into) has 'to grow into something': _4. Lit. to grow enough to fit into something. The shirt is a little large, but Timmy will grow into it. My shoes are too big, but I will grow into them._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single word antonym in that situation (at least, none I am aware of).

The idiomatic phrase to use would be:

> I lost so much weight that I *had to tighten* my belt!

or for another article of clothing, perhaps:

> I lost so much weight that I *had to take in* my pants.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think **outgrew** can be used with belt, i.e. ***I outgrew my belt***.

I think what you are looking for is:

> I lost so much weight that I had to ***tighten*** my belt.

and to explain the original situation:

> I added so much weight that I had to ***loosen*** my belt.

Comment: It is possible to grow so much that the belt is actually too short (and consequently simply loosening would no longer be enough). Although *outgrow* is not usually applied to belts, it's exactly the same as a baby outgrowing his romper suit.